# Login with twitter api

Tags: authentication, twitter, twitter-oauth

When I`m trying to integrate login with twitter in my website, I get the following message

```
array(1) {
    ["errors"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
            ["message"]=> string(31) "Sorry, that page does not exist" 
            ["code"]=> int(34) 
        } 
    }  
}
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Which URL do you use for logging in?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

You just follow the instruction for login with twitter integration.